# Vim suspending when opening file

Tags: vim

I'm using archlinux with zsh and vim 7.3 ( https://gist.github.com/4114299 ). I'm not using tmux/screen.

Whenever I open a file (with plugins enabled) or try execute a shell command (using `:!`)/editing a file with no plugins enabled, my vim session suspends and I have to use the `fg` command to respawn my session. Either way, vim keeps suspending itself without me doing anything.

I never had that problem before and I can't reproduce the problem with gvim. The problem is only vim related.

Here are my vim files: https://github.com/marcosdsanchez/.vim/

And this is the vimrc file I'm using on my project: https://gist.github.com/2d64b3f258b14b486284

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was this line in my vimrc file:

```
set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

Erasing that fixed my problem.